# Getting error while testing Spring Boot REST controller with multipart file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/agents/log/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CallbackResponse> agentsLogFileUpload(@RequestParam("eventId") String id,
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws ResourceNotFoundException, IOException {

    agentLogService.saveLogFile(file, file.getName(), id);
    eventService.updateEvent(id, new ExecutionSummary(Status.SUCCEEDED),    
                                serviceAuthClient.getDefaultJwtTokenObserver().getJwtAccessToken());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new CallbackResponse(true), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have written the following test method

```
@Test
public void testAgentsLogFileUpload() throws Exception {

    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "multipart/form-data", "Test".getBytes());
    AgentLog agentLog = new AgentLog();
    Mono<Event> event = Mono.just(new Event());

    Mockito.when(agentLogService.saveLogFile(Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(agentLog);
    Mockito.when(eventService.updateEvent(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(event);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/agents/log/upload").file(file)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE).param("eventId", "123");
    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn();
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
}
```

I added the stacktace of my test method below.

```
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <200> but was: <500>
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:510)
        at com.cygilant.endpoint.security.cloud.rest.controller.ExecutionControllerTest.testAgentsLogFileUpload(ExecutionControllerTest.java:204)
```

When I run this test I'm getting HTTP Error 500 and NullPointerException. Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: If there an error 500, there should be an exception. Could you provide it?

Comment: NullPointer Exception

Comment: Why the test mapping is "/agents/log/upload" and postMapping value is "/managers/log/upload"?

Comment: i added wrong method i am updaing it

Comment: Also add the error trace to understand better

Comment: @RajuKomati sorry, I meant a stacktrace, could you provide it in the question?